# cURL help required for lolabits.es website, i want to fetch video download url

Tags: php, curl

I am fetching the download link url from lolabits.es website. I am giving it input of exact url of video and want to print its download link. 
Code i am using is:
require_once 'functions.php';

```
$referer        = 'http://lolabits.es/AdrielxD/One+Piece/One+Piece+700+*7e+750/One+Piece+-+729,76621268.mp4(video';
$post  = '';
$cookieFileName = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "temp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "cookie2.txt"; 
$answer = curl_request($referer, false, true, $cookieFileName);
$page = $answer;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

$total_page = $xml->xpath("//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']");
$reqToken  = $total_page[0]->attributes()->value;

//$action = $xml->xpath("//form[@class='download_form']");
//echo $action  = $action[0]->attributes()->action;

$fileID = $xml->xpath("//input[@name='FileId']");
$fileID  = $fileID[0]->attributes()->value;

echo $URL = "http://lolabits.es/action/License/Download"; echo "<br>";
echo $post = "?fileId=".$fileID."&__RequestVerificationToken=$reqToken";
echo $answer = curl_request($URL, $post, 'Content-Type: application/x-www-    form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                            true, $cookieFileName, false, $referer);

echo "<br><br><br>";            
$link = json_encode($answer);
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo $link = json_decode($answer);

echo $link->redirectUrl;
```

Let me know where i am wrong,, and suggest the best solution please. 
I am attaching the temper data image too for it.

Temper Data Image
[image]

Comment: You may want to post the code for `curl_request()` as well